# The code keeps executing despite return statement - ERROR Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js, async-await

I wonder what causes the problem.

I use Next.js with Next Auth to build my fullstack app and I am securing my API routes. In my API route, I am checking if user is authenticated - simply if there's `token`.

If there's no `token`, I want request to fail, send failed message and return immediately.

As this validation shows up in multiple API routes, I decided to outsource this as a seperate function.

**checkIfAuthenticated.js**

```
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt';

const checkIfAuthenticated = async (req, res) => {
  const token = await getToken({ req });

  if (!token) {
    res.status(401).json({ message: 'Protected resource, no access granted.' });
    return;
  }
};

export default checkIfAuthenticated;
```

**/api/articles/index.js**

```
const handler = async (req, res) => {
  //If user is not authenticated, request will fail
  await checkIfAuthenticated(req, res);

  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    let client;
    try {
      client = await connectDb();
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Connecting to the database failed.' });
    }

    const database = client.db('mindescape');
    const collection = database.collection('articles');

    try {
      const articles = await collection.find({}).toArray();
      res.status(200).json({ articles: articles });
      client.close();
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Connecting to the database failed.' });
      client.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Why the execution isn't stopped and goes to another if block throwing that `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` error? I know what this error means that the API is sending multiple responses.
**However if I don't make** `checkIfAuthenticated` **as a seperate function and just paste it straight to the API route, it all works like a charm.** So what the heck? :)

```
if (req.method === 'GET') {
//THIS CODE IS EXECUTED EVEN THO SHOULDNT
}
```

Thanks in advance :)
Maciej

Comment: It looks like you expect the return statement in checkIfAuthenticated to trigger a return from handler.  Doesn't work like that, each function is independent.

Comment: Oh definitely youre right. I spent a long time  working on this project. My mind isn't fresh now. Massive thanks for clearing it up. All the best mate :)